Why switching to SMB2+ results in a "process cannot access file" error?
This error started occurring at high volume installations when SMB1 is disabled:

The process cannot access the file '\user1.Log.txt' because it is being used by another process.

The logs are by user, and this happens only if there are multiple users, which doesn't make sense. Multiple applications can write to the log file, so they are opened with share lock. The logs are accessed by C++Builder and .Net applications, but so far all of the errors seem to be coming from .Net. Also, the application is shared across users via Citrix.
Any idea why SMB2/3 causes the error to happen?
C++Builder:
StreamWriter = new TStreamWriter(new TFileStream(FileNameAndPath, fmOpenWrite | fmShareDenyNone), TEncoding::UTF8, 1024);

C#:
using (var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite)) 
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream))
using (var writer = TextWriter.Synchronized(streamWriter))
{
  if (stream.Length == 0)
  {
    writer.WriteLine(GetLogHeader (userId, stationId));
  }
    
  // Write the message, then close the log.
  writer.WriteLine(GetLogMessage (program, shortMsg, LongMsg));
}

